# Crash when trying to get minimal element in array

Tags: c++

Homework: Three vectors A [n], B [m], C [k] given are given. For each one find the minimal element.

Problem: program crashes when it must find minimal element in each array

I suppose its because i wrote return 0 in GetMin function but i dont know what am i supposed to write there (sounds stupid, but im novice and kinda frustrated now). Changing 0 to min, min2, min3 gives big strangen numbers.

```
int GetMin(int*a, int n, int*b, int m, int*c, int k)
{
    int min = a[0];
    for(int x = 0; x < n; ++x)
    {
        if(a[n] < min)
        {
            min = a[n];
        }
    }

    int min2 = b[0];
    for(int x = 0; x < n; ++x)
    {
        if(b[m] < min2)
        {
            min2 = b[m];
        }
    }

    int min3 = c[0];
    for(int x = 0; x < n; ++x)
    {
        if(c[k] < min3)
        {
            min3 = c[k];
        }
    }
    return 0;
}


int main()
{
    int n, m, k;

    cout << "Enter size of first vector: ";
    cin >> n;
    cout << endl;
    int*a = new int[n];
    cout << "Enter vector elements: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cin >> a[i];
    }
    cout << endl;

    cout << "Enter size of second vector: ";
    cin >> m;
    cout << endl;
    int*b = new int[m];
    cout << "Enter vector elements: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        cin >> b[i];
    }
    cout << endl;

    cout << "Enter size of third vector: ";
    cin >> k;
    cout << endl;
    int*c = new int[k];
    cout << "Enter vector elements: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
    {
        cin >> c[i];
    }
    cout << endl;

    int result = GetMin(a, n, b, m, c, k);
    cout << "Minimal element = " << result << endl;

    delete[]a;
    delete[]b;
    delete[]c;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at [std::min_element](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min_element)? There's no need to re-invent the wheel.

Comment: What did you observe when stepping through your code line by line with the debugger? Where exactly the _"crash"_ happens? What were the variable values at that point?

Comment: Write a function that finds the minimum element in *one* array and use that function three times.

Comment: Besides the obvious typo that's responsible for the crash here, the correct solution will involve exactly one `for` loop. Not three. If you figure out what the bug is, even if you fix it, as is, your instructor will unlikely to give you full credit for this homework assignment.

Comment: How can i make this with one loop? What should i change "a[0]" and "n" to?

Comment: You should refactor the code to just work on one array. Then call it for each array after you enter the data. Anytime you find yourself repeating code you should think: simplify. You might read ahead and read this https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min_element as it will be in your future, but don't worry, get the basics down first.

Answer (score 0):

The immediate problem is that you haven't been paying attention to your array bounds and loop variables.

`m`, `n`, and `k` are invalid indexes, and none of your loops use the loop variables for indexing.

The first one should look like this:

```
int min = a[0];
for(int x = 0; x < n; ++x)
{
    if(a[x] < min)
    {
        min = a[x];
    }
}
```

Wrap that loop in a function, and you can find the minimum elements in any amount of arrays.

Comment: Like this? 
`int GetMin(int*a, int n, int*b, int m, int*c, int k)
{
   int min = a[0];
for(int x = 0; x < n; ++x)
{
    if(a[x] < min)
    {
        min = a[x];
    }
}
    return min;
}`

Comment: @Favoras You only need the first two parameters.